# What is the grammatical function of 好感度さえ in 好感度さえクリアしていれば?

Tags: grammar, particle-さえ

> 秋葉さんのルートは他のルートとは違っていて、**好感度さえ**クリアしていればグッド・トゥルー、共に特別な条件を必要としません。

さえ.

This is the particle which always give me problems.
How can I translate this sentence?
I can't really grasp it.

I tried to and my translation would be:

> Akiha's route is different from the others and as long as you clear it favorably the true and good ending, together they do not require necessary conditions.

Still makes no sense.

Comment: Tsukihime, right? It's saying that all you need to get the good/true end for Akiha's route is enough "Akiha points" (好感度), and not any other special conditions (e.g. specific dialogue choices) (特別な条件). 好感度さえクリアしていれば means "as long as your 好感度 'clears' a given threshold...".

Comment: Yes tsukihime.

I tought clear was referring to the the game.

So what 好感度 means generally?

Why is 共に used before special conditions?

Comment: In this case, クリアする doesn't mean "to clear a route"; it means "to achieve a condition", the condition in this case being sufficient 好感度. In general, 好感度 means "degree of favor"; in VNs, that translates to "how many points have you earned for this character". 共に is used here because the previous clause refers to グッド and トゥルー, and it's saying that _both_ of those don't require any other special conditions.

Comment: I usually think of 好感度 as "likability" or "like meter/stat".  Some games even have a number (or levels) to show how much the character likes you, like other stats in RPGs.

Comment: This question is possibly about ~さえ~ば, as opposed to being about 好感度

Answer (score 1):

Role of さえ translated in bold:

'Unlike other routes, Akiba's route doesn't require [...], **as long as** you make a good impression ("obtain enough good will points").'